# igraph adding multiple pre-requisites for attribute value replacement

Tags: r, igraph

So I have a graph and code like the following:

```
g <- make_ring(10) %>%
set_vertex_attr("a", value = 3) %>%
set_vertex_attr("b", value = 2) %>%
add_vertices(10, color = 4, "a" = 2, "b" = 3) %>%
add_vertices(10, color = 4, "a" = 2, "b" = 4)
g

V(g)$a[V(g)$a == 2] = 1
V(g)$a
```

I want to change the

```
V(g)$a[V(g)$a == 2] = 1
```

so that more pre requisites must be satisfied before the value of "a" changes to 1

I tried doing

```
V(g)$a[V(g)$a == 2,V(g)$b == 4] = 1
```

but it returned:
Error in V(g)$a[V(g)$a == 2, V(g)$b == 4] = 1 : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix. How would I rewrite this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just want

```
V(g)$a[V(g)$a == 2 & V(g)$b == 4] = 1 
V(g)$a
[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```